# Getting RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error accessing field on custom form

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm relatively new to Django (and python in general) and I'm working on project I have not coded myself.

Specifically I'm trying to save some information from a form via `POST` but I get a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error when accessing the `user` field defined in my custom `Profile` model and I don't get why.

Here is my `views.py`:

```python
def conferma(request):
    family = request.user.profile.family  # cannot be null
    already_confirmed = request.user.profile.conferma_inviata

    if(already_confirmed == False):

        ProfileFormSet = modelformset_factory(
            Profile, form=ConfirmForm, extra=0)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            formset = ProfileFormSet(
                request.POST, queryset=Profile.objects.filter(family=family))
            if formset.is_valid():
                for form in formset:
                    f = form.save(commit=False)
                    f.conferma_inviata = True
                    f.save()
```

If I try to access `f.user` I get a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error and I need that information in order to save the form.

Here is my forms.py:

```python
class ConfirmForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'conferma_pranzo',
                  'conferma_sera', 'conferma_inviata',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConfirmForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].required = False
        self.fields['conferma_inviata'].required = False
```

Here is my `models.py`:

```python
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_day = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    family = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    conferma_pranzo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    conferma_sera = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    conferma_inviata = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name
```

I have already checked the Database but the `Profile` records are correctly stored with the proper `userd_id` reference.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT This is the traceback when I try to view the `user` field on the form via variable inspector of the debugger:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/simone/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.9.114305/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py", line 193, in _get_py_dictionary
    attr = getattr(var, name)
  File "/home/simone/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 198, in __get__
    "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name)
invitations.models.Profile.user.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Profile has no user.
```

Answer (score 0):

OneToOneField reverse relationships throw errors in django when a relation does not exist (as opposed to ForeignKeys which return a None type).

Without the traceback I am not entirely sure where you error is, however something like this *might* help:

models.py:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

class Profile(models.Model):

    # add related name argument to user field for reverse accessing:
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')
    ...

class User(...):
    ...
    
    # return a None type when a reverse relation does not exist (instead of an IntegrityError)
    @property
    def profile(self): 
        try: return self.user_profile
        except IntegrityError: return None
```

views.py:

```
def conferma(request):

    # do something if the user has a profile:
    if request.user.profile:
        ...

    # do something else if the user does not have a profile:
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer! I attached the exact traceback in the original post.
I don't undestand why I get this error since I'm trying to access the user from the profile form. 
The profile in the request.user is present (and with the user attribute as well) but I'm interested in the formset profiles which does not contain any users.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood so far the `user` data are not sent in the POST within the `Profile` in the `ConfirmForm`.

This is the template where the POST come from:

```
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        <table align="center" class="w3-table-all" style="width:100%; max-width:400px">

            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                {% if user.profile.full_day %}
                <th class="w3-center">Conferma pranzo</th>
                {% endif %}
                <th class="w3-center">Conferma sera (dalle 18:30)</th>

            </tr>
            {% for form in formset %}

            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.instance.user.first_name }}</td>
                {% if user.profile.full_day %}
                <td class="w3-center">{{ form.conferma_pranzo }}</td>
                {% endif %}
                <td class="w3-center">{{ form.conferma_sera }}</td>

                {{form.id}}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Invia conferma">
      </form>
```

How can I add that information?